# Efficient way of calculating maximum area span

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, vectors

I have a question which looks like this.

Assuming i have a case of 3 tuples. All elements are vectors.

```
(a,b,c)
(d,e,f)
(g,h,i)
```

How do i find the pair of vectors that gives the smallest amount of cosine similarity when summed together.

Basically i would like to have this.

Exhaustive manner to get the answer i seek.

Computing the cartesian product element wise in all the tuples and obtaining the pairing that gives the smallest value. In other words.

The way i am doing is like this now.

```
a*b*c 
a*e*c
a*h*c
a*b*f
a*e*f
a*h*f
a*b*i
a*e*i
a*h*i
```

This pattern is repeated for d and g likewise. Assume that * is a dot product

Comment: Let me see if this is what you are asking. You have a set $S$ of $n$ dimensional vectors, and you want $ s\subset S $ such that $|s|=3$ and $ s^* = \arg\min_{s} \sum_i u_i v_i w_i  $ where $ {u,v,w\in s} $. Are you asking for an algorithm to get this? Is something wrong with what you're doing?

Comment: Yes i think you got what i mean. But the thing is the manner i am doing is expensive if i have say 100 vectors to choose from instead of simply 3. The complexity is like length of tuple ^ 3

Comment: Might not make a big difference, but you could consider caching intermediate results. i.e. Let $S=\{s_1,\ldots,s_n\}$ where $s_i\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and compute $ u(i,j) = (s_i(1)s_j(1),\ldots,s_i(m)s_j(m)) $. Then the quantity you want seems to be $ \arg\min v(i,j,k) $, where
$ v(i,j,k) = u(i,j)\cdot s_k = \sum_\ell u_\ell(i,j) s_k(\ell) $. At least then you won't repeat many of the intermediate multiplications I think.